# Can an id be encoded as a feature for a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Say for example each user has their own unique model, say for example a users music taste.  Sure I could encode generic features of their taste, but I want it to be truly specific and personalized per user. However, rather than making N different models, I encode N as a feature to my model, (0->N). E.g:

```
age, eye color, time of day, user_id
```

Lets say for now, I'm working with a neural network.  Thoughts on whether a the user_id would be enough of a feature to produce different results for each user?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely! This is exactly what you can use *one-hot encoding* for. However, this means you will have `N` extra inputs (where `N` is the amount of users).

If you have three users, the extra input to your model would look like this:

```
user1: 001
user2: 010
user3: 100
```

[image]

---

However, if you are running neural computations for a lot of users, you should probably use a network that is indifferent to the user ID (even though you said you didn't want that). Maybe look at some kind of recurrent network (LSTM).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let's say N is reasonably large, why not just input the id (integer) as a feature itself? Too much "stress" on the network to learn? One hot encoding makes sense for smaller N, but it might be too much for the network. Perhaps N models makes sense, as long as it's quick to load the network, thoughts?

Comment: @carboncomputed just because an `id` is an integer, doesn't mean it is a numerical value. It should be always treated as a categorical value, except if there is a steady relation between `n` and  `n+1` for example. If you input and `id` as an integer, then the network will think that `id=20` is twice as big as `id=10`, although there is no relation that way whatsoever. I think you should stick with some kind of recurrent model that works for every user, so id's can be disregarded.